# Removal of the notification bar in an Android app

Tags: android, android-widget, themes, fullscreen

I'm developing an restaurant menu application that I want to be always on (the user shouldn't be able to go outside the application).

So far am able to override the back and home buttons, but I would like to get rid of the notification bar. Is there anyway to do such thing?

I've tried to set the app theme to fullscreen no title bar but that didn't do the trick. (For the home button i used the custom app in the application.xml.)

Here is a picture of the app for better understanding 
[image: screenshot of my app]

Comment: whoever rated this down . did u even read ?

Comment: I've edited your question to improve it for you. It was likely downvoted because it was very poorly asked.

Comment: @IbrahemAhmed that's the thing in S.O. full of arrogance; don't feel powerless

Comment: BTW you may include in your question/title if there's a way to force the app to stay; regardless of the notification bar. But it does feel a bit off Google's way

Comment: is it even possible with flashing the ROM ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove bottom navigation bar (notification bar is that one on the top of the screen) on non-rooted device.

If you want to make kiosk mode, then you got two choices - turn your app into launcher or root your device and use tools like: http://ppareit.github.com/HideBar/ (there's open source solution as well but I do not have URL handy)

Comment: i want to remove the bar highlighted in the picture

Comment: I am talking about exactly that one

Comment: well if i turn my app into a launcher. the user can still go to settings uninstall the app

Comment: can  you give the link open source solution?

Answer (score 0):

Put this onCreate()

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // Removing the title 

this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
//notification bar
```

But you have to put it before the call to setContentView(R.id.x), otherwise it does not work

Comment: this is have the same effect as setting the theme in the xml file . and it wont overlay the notification bar